# best way to look for a keyword inside a string when working with huge lists of keywords and strings

Tags: php, mysql

I want to build a lookup table and I'm working with enough data to myself dizzy. I would like some advice on what is the proper way to run this iteration without it taking forever.

So I have two tables

- Table 1 (movies)

  - contains over 1 million movie plots normally not longer than 100 words
- Table 2 (names)

  - is a table containing ~9000 movie character names

I want to build a lookup table that will have a row everytime a "movie character name" is mentionned inside a "movie plot".

So each row will be a combination of `movieID` and `nameID`

What is the most optimized way to build this table?

The slow way would be to iterate through every "character name" and then performing a mysql:

```
SELECT * WHERE movie_plot LIKE '%characted_name%'
```

but boy that would take forever.

Perhaps a less slow way would be to store the entire list of names in an php array, then iterate through each "movie plot", explode the "movie plot" on spaces and then iterate through each word and use `isset($character_names[$word])`

Could anyone suggest a better way? Assuming I only have php/mysql to work with, so no sphix and no elastic search

Many thanks

Comment: Why not create a new table that is just movieID and nameID?  Then you can easily search.

Comment: Is the time it takes really a concern? You should only have to do it once and then do it for each new plot as a new movie gets added. You could do it in batches and keep track in an additional column which movies have been processed. Then you could set up a cron job do do it in the hours the site is not used much (if any...).

Comment: I mean of course which names have already been processed, not which plots...